# remapping Hyper to Caps Lock, which is a remap of F19…

Tags: keyboard, remapping

I configured a custom Hyper key from [this article](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/a-modern-space-cadet/#hyper) by Steve Losh.

With my job computer, it's working.
With my home computer, it's not working… I have a F19 key on my keyboard, so the event handler of KeyRemap4MacBook tells me that my computer knows the key is not really *pressed*.

So… I’m looking for another keycode I could use with my Apple Keyboard with Numeric Keypad.
Any clue…?

Answer (score 0):

Once more, I found my answer by myself…
You need to select the good keyboard if you have more than one (laptop and regular keyboard).
[here's a screenshot](http://d.pr/i/rOgY)